# Нужна ли запятая: парк дизельных погрузчиков(,) грузоподъемностью от 3 до 4 тонн

Tags: пунктуация

Нужна ли здесь запятая в уточняющем обороте?

"Полностью обновлены парк дизельных погрузчиков(,) грузоподъемностью от 3 до 4 тонн и автопарк, состоящий из трех среднетоннажных автомобилей".

Answer (score 1):

Правильно: "Полностью обновлены парк дизельных погрузчиков грузоподъемностью от 3 до 4 тонн и автопарк, состоящий из трех среднетоннажных автомобилей".

Обособление несогласованных определений делается при уточнении, когда обозначается сопутствующий признак, а здесь грузоподъемность является отличительным (важным) признаком.

Сравнить: Доски размером более трёх метров отложите в сторону. Но: Доски, размером около трёх метров, уложены на платформе.

Answer (score 0):

Тогда уж и вторую ставьте, после "тонн", а то что же... с одной стороны обособились, а с другой нет.

Но обособление здесь не требуется. Вряд ли это можно рассматривать как уточнение.
Однако "тонн и автопарк" смотрится плоховато. Я бы написал: "Полностью обновлеН парк...грузоподъемностью от 3 до 4 тонн, а также автопарк..."

Comment: Спасибо. ))) Обособлялась не я, и мне это тоже не нравится.

Answer (score 0):

Да, здесь не нужно обособление
.